# How to cast Date from varchar to DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hey I have column called `DATE_Hour` in my table which is `varchar` and has values like

```
Tue, 29 Jul 2014 14:00
```

How can I convert that date in to `2014-07-29 14:00:00.000`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it consistently has the day of the week followed by a comma, you can use:

```
SELECT CAST(STUFF(DATE_Hour,1,CHARINDEX(',',DATE_Hour),'')AS DATETIME)
FROM YourTable
```

The format: '29 Jul 2014 14:00' will cast without issue, but the day of the week preceding that is not an accepted format, so you just use `STUFF()` to strip off the day then `CAST()` what remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = 'Tue, 29 Jul 2014 14:00'

PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(RIGHT(@str,LEN(@str)-CHARINDEX(',',@str))  AS DATETIME),121)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work no matter what you have in there for the day of the week (i.e. could be WED, THURS, etc. just in case your day of the week isn't always three characters):

```
DECLARE @VarcharTime VARCHAR(50) = 'Tue, 29 Jul 2014 14:00'
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@VarcharTime, PATINDEX('%, %',@VarcharTime)+2, LEN(@VarcharTime)) AS DATETIME)
```

EDIT: This will also work with `PATINDEX('%,%',@VarcharTime)+1` if you're interested in saving characters :)